# read text from left most cell only

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

I have a lot of tables in a docx file and I'm trying to get text from cells from first columns.

I have this code for searching in full rows

```
for table in doc.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                result = ReqRegex.search(paragraph.text)
                if result:
                    file.write(result.group()+"\n")
```

but I'm trying to change it to check only first columns

```
for table in doc.tables:
    for column in table.columns:
        for cell in table.column_cells(0):
            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                result = ReqRegex.search(paragraph.text)
                if result:
                    file.write(result.group()+"\n")
```

Can you tell me what can I change to make this code work?

Comment: wouldn't it be `for cell in column.cells:' in the third row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved my problem. Maybe it will be useful for someone

```
for table in doc.tables:
    rowNo = 0
    for row in table.rows:
        columnNo = 0
        for cell in row.cells:
            columnNo += 1
            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                result = ReqRegex.search(paragraph.text)
                if columnNo == 1:
                    print(cell.text)
                    if result:
                        file.write(result.group()+"\n")
        rowNo += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with working with python-docx, but by normal python rules, this should work

```
for table in doc.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
            for paragraph in row.cells(0).paragraphs:
                result = ReqRegex.search(paragraph.text)
                if result:
                    file.write(result.group()+"\n")
```